# passing oracle query from c#

Tags: c#, plsqldeveloper

Does anyone know what does it reflects when passing a query from C# code to oracle database?

Select first_name, last_name from database_name@whatisthis

I'm particularly interested in @ sign then the word whatisthis, I mean, is it a linked server or a remote database name etc.

Thanks

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: The best place to start is the Oracle SQL [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm), which is good quality and very straightforward. The local community is helpful, but you would need to show that you did some effort to investigate your question.

Comment: Returning to your question, using AT (@) symbol is usually reffering on special syntax that was introduced to support distributed queries (queries that need to query data from different databases).

Comment: All i'm looking for is what what follows after @ in oracle. I'm able to execute the query using the .net Code but when I try to execute the same sql from the SQL Developer studio, it gives me error at @here

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write the query as below:

```
"Select first_name, last_name from database_name where name =:name"
```

where :name would be parameter we would like to send

```
query.AddParameter("name",actual_Value)
```

after this execute query.

This solved my problem